# How can I solve ruby on rails Segmentation fault on macOS Catalina?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have ruby on rails that used to work without any problems but after upgrading to macOS Catalina it seems giving a segmentation error.

Error goes as follows.

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin18]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0003 p:---- s:0011 e:000010 CFUNC  :sleep
c:0002 p:0021 s:0006 e:000005 BLOCK  /Users/waruna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@loke-server/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:283 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:---- s:0003 e:000002 (none) [FINISH]
```

Then when you look at the `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` it shows following.

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        4  thread_pool.rb*  Dispatch queue: com.apple.security.keychain-cache-queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x110:
```

I have tried cleaning the bundle and reinstalling ruby gems, giving full disk access to ruby and rails command line and cloning the project again and running it, but non of that worked.

However if I create a sample ruby on rails app that seems to work fine without any problems.

Anyone else run into this problem and managed to solved it, or any ideas you might have would immensely help.

Comment: Did you also update `homebrew`?

Comment: @gautam yes, I did

Comment: One idea is to use a virtual machine to run the OS you're actually deploying to. I'm guessing its not OS-X.

Comment: So, I managed to solve this problem by downgrading to postgresql 11.6 from postgresql 12. 

But it could not be the postgresql itself, but maybe the connector. But for now this will do the trick. I could further investigate this later and leave comments if i find anything new

Comment: Looks like this is related

https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/311

I am guessing the `gssencmode: disable` in your database.yml can workaround the error.

Comment: @BenoitPatra You are a gentleperson and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, either uninstall and reinstall postgres with homebrew, or add `gssencmode: "disable"` to database.yml. More info here: https://gist.github.com/jjb/cf1a7623514e621adc58afdc43b87b63

Comment: Fixed the issue with MacOS Version 14.1.2 Sonoma.